# What does yuv420 output mean in camera?

Tags: signal-processing, image-sensor

Now I'm reading a datasheet which is ov5642.

www.uctronics.com/download/cam_module/OV5642DS.pdf

But I can't understand the explain table6-6 format control register of yuv420.

Q1.How does yuv420 could be express such as "YYYY..../YUYV...."?
Exactly what does it mean ? Does datasheet wrote as right?

Q2.Exactly, how does yuv420 real cameara make the output?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling#4:2:0

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 ,  Thanks sir,  does it mean YYYY.... / YUYVYUYV.... / YYYYYY..../YUYUYUYV.......?

Comment: equations are defined by YCbCr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
The subsample code letters for the suffix numbers are J:a:b for YUV J:a:b 

J: horizontal sampling reference (width of the conceptual region). Usually, 4.
a: number of chrominance samples (Cr, Cb) in the first row of J pixels.
b: number of changes of chrominance samples (Cr, Cb)
    between first and second row of J pixels.
```

Thus YUV420 uses 4H samples with 2 samples of Cr,Cb in the 1st of 3 rows with 0 between 1st & 2nd row.

The Omnivision specifies the formatter output sequence is correctly given as:

[image]
[image]

> Like SECAM, 4:2:0 only stores and transmits one color channel per line (the other channel being recovered from the previous line.